# values getting duplicated in list

Tags: apex

I am getting the dupe values as soon as i add the data to list in the below code,
i even tried to put the data into set and addAll to list, but i am getting dupes. am i missing some thing here? can any one please help!

```
list<Opportunity> listOpp = new list<Opportunity>();//List to store the OppSize with stageName!=ClosedWon||SW Job Cancelled
List<Partner_Detail__c> PartnerLst = new List<Partner_Detail__c>();
Partner_Detail__c pd= new Partner_Detail__c() ;
set<Partner_Detail__c> PartnerFcount = new set<Partner_Detail__c>();//Final Count that will be updated
List<Partner_Detail__c> Comupdate = new List<Partner_Detail__c>();
PartnerLst=[select Id,Total_Number_of_Lots__c,(select id from Opportunities__r where StageName NOT IN ('Closed Won','SW Job Cancelled')) from Partner_Detail__c where id in ('a0Ya000000AChg3EAD','a0Ya000000BCaBKEA1')];
for(Partner_Detail__c a:PartnerLst){
    if(a.Opportunities__r!=null && a.Opportunities__r.size()>0)
              {
                 listOpp =a.Opportunities__r;
                 system.debug('listOppSize '+listOpp.size());
                 system.debug('a.Total_Number_of_Lots__c '+a.Total_Number_of_Lots__c);
                 pd.Id=a.Id;
                 Pd.Total_Number_of_Lots_Remaining__c=(a.Total_Number_of_Lots__c - listOpp.size());
                 //system.debug('a.Total_Number_of_Lots_Remaining__c '+a.Total_Number_of_Lots_Remaining__c);
                 system.debug('pd object '+pd);
                 system.debug('Adding once ');
                 PartnerFcount.add(pd);
                 system.debug('PartnerFcount '+PartnerFcount);
}

}
system.debug('Set data '+PartnerFcount);
Comupdate.addAll(PartnerFcount);
    system.debug('last '+Comupdate);
```

Comment: You are adding the same instance of Partner_Detail__c (created on line 3) multiple times to the list. Moving `pd= new Partner_Detail__c()` inside the loop should avoid that but there may well be other problems in the code.

Comment: Have you Debugged your code And check what it is returning for "PartnerFcount" . Does it contains duplicate values

Comment: @KeithC Moving the object instance to for loop solved it. thanks.

Comment: @KeithC Dang man you keep putting `Answers` in the comments!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Didn't have the will power to provide an answer that really explains what is going on. If you do +1 from me...